# grep at multiple files, then cut at those files, then cut at another file, then diff between those 2 files

Tags: unix, grep, diff, cut

What I need to do is the following **3 operations at 1 single line**, if possible:

1) `grep -h A1234 BATCHFILE.201509* | cut -c 38-49 > file1.out`

(Note: Here I use the ':' delimiter, because there are many BATCHFILE.201509xxxx files, for which the grep returns:

```
BATCHFILE.2015091915: ..............
BATCHFILE.2015091918: ..............
BATCHFILE.2015091922: ..............
```

So, I cut for characters 38 till 49 from results after the ':'.)

2) Then I need to cut for characters 38 till 49 at a file "WORKFILE.IN":

```
cut -c 38-49 WORKFILE.IN > file2.out
```

3) Then I need to find the differences between the 2 files extracted:

```
diff file1.out file2.out
```

Thank you.

Comment: `grep -h  A1234 BATCHFILE.201509* ` will surpress the filename output so you don't need to remove it

Comment: How many files are we talking about, and what shell are you using? Stand-alone tools like grep and diff and cut will necessarily require multiple commands, but if you're using bash or ksh you may be able to reduce the calls to external tools by utilizing data structures like arrays.  More information about what you're actually trying to achieve, including samples of the data, would help us create better answers.

Comment: "1 single line" seems like a quite arbitrary and very useless restraint

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -h A1234 BATCHFILE.201509* | cut -c 38-49 > file1.out && cut -c 38-49 WORKFILE.IN > file2.out && diff file1.out file2.out
```

Well technically there is a single line.   the `-h` option to grep will suppress  the filename from being output when multiple files are searched, and the `&&` will chain the commands so they are run only if the previous completes.

I still question the need for 1 line, though.  simple shell script with the steps/variables might be better /  easier to understand

diff with anonymous pipelines

```
diff <(grep -h A1234 BATCHFILE.201509* | cut -c 38-49) <(cut -c 38-49 WORKFILE.IN)
```

Comment: OK, this works, many thanks!!!  Is there a way not to use the file1.out and file2.out files at all, and just diff the outputs of the 2 cuts (no out files involved), or I am asking too much?  :)

Comment: Assuming 2 files you should be able to use anonymous pipelines (works in bash and zsh at least).   See my edit.